# How to load static files in python bottle in URL's

Tags: python, bottle

I'm working on a python app in Python Bottle. The app works fine if I'm on 1 lvl deep URLs like /dashboard or /rules or /page. However, if I go deeper like /dashboard/overview or /rules/ruleone or /page/test the CSS, JS, fonts and images will fail. :(

The HTML source code still poinsts to /assets/ but if I'm on an URL like /rules/ruleone, the right path should be something like ../assets or ./assets right? The path /assets/ only works on the first level but not on deeper lvls, in other words: bottle doesnt adapt the static file path to the current directory. How do I fix this?

I'm stuck on this problem for days now, I realy hope someone can help me. :(

My code (simplified):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import lib.bottle as bottle
from lib.bottle import route, template, debug, static_file, TEMPLATE_PATH, error, auth_basic, get, post, request, response, run, view, redirect, SimpleTemplate, HTTPError, abort
import os, sys, re

@route('/dashboard')
@view('secure_page')
def show__page_dashboard():
    return dict(page = 'Dashboard')

@route('/rules/<rule>')
@view('secure_page')
def show_page_rules_more(rule):
    return dict(page = rule)

@route('/assets/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='/var/myapp/assets')

TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "view")))

bottle.debug(True)
from lib.bottledaemon import daemon_run
if __name__ == "__main__":
    daemon_run()
```

So my app runs in daemon mode. The structure is:

lib

- bottle.py
- bottledaemon.py

assets

- css
- js
- ...

view

- secure_page.tpl
- footer.tpl
- header.tpl
- ...

server.py

I hope someone can help me out on this, thanks in advance guys, I love u! <3

Comment: how in the mark up how you are accessing the static files? if you access them in an absolute manner, it shouldn't change regardless of the active page's URI

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright I found the solution for my problem. Bottle offers an URL tag to dynamicly build URLs.

```
from bottle import url

@route('/dashboard')
@view('secure_page')
def show__page_dashboard():
    return dict(page='Dashboard', url=url)

@route('/assets/<filepath:path>', name='assets')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='/var/myapp/assets')
```

This is how I load my CSS/JS/images

```
<link href="{{ url('assets', filepath='css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Dynamic menu URL's (in the navigation for example) is done this way:

```
{{ url('/dashboard') }}
```

I hope this info will help someone who is strugling with the same problem as I was.

Tested on v0.12 and v0.13dev

Comment: I got into the same trouble here, but I got many routes like your /dashboard whose return values are calculated from some other functions, and modifying them to include url is kind of complicated, is there any direct way of passing default values to the templates, BTW I'm using jinja2 templates instead of the bottle's simple templates

Answer (score 3):

I do use:

```
@route('/css/<filename>')
def stylesheets(filename):
return static_file(filename, root='./static/css/')
```

and in template use:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

can be replicated for all assets items (img, css, and js)

Comment: The decorator `@route()` can be replaced also by `@get()` decorator.